# Fixing header in 960 grid based theme

Tags: html, css

i am trying to fix header in this way

```
.container_24 header-container{
position:fixed;
}
```

This fixed the header, but the main container block just below it now aligned to top.
The probable solution i tried was giving content block a top margin. Alas. the theme specifies main contnet div in this way

```
.container_24 em-main{
/* css code */
    }
```

U must hav got my point, as giving it a margin is pushing the header down alongwith. I suspect the `container_24` as my problem. 
Its a magento 960 grid theme, and i cant take risk of adding some additional wrapper of main content in core.
Looking for some help in getting this get to go
And hey.. here is the link  [Link Removed] if u want to check wid chrome dev tools .. or firebug

Thanks

Comment: is `header-container` a class or id? You haven't specified, same with `em-main`

Comment: @AndyHolmes both them are class, but they have been call together with .container_24 as u can see on link. Thank u for reply :-)

Comment: you should still write it as `.container_24 .header-container {}` and `.container_24 .em-main {}` though

Comment: but this declaration came wid the theme as it is.
Anyway i'll make sure i clarify same when asking thank u :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.em-header {
    background: url(../images/digital_blue/bkg-header.png) 0 0 repeat #b50728;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.em-main {
    top: 122px;
    position: relative;
}
```

That should do what you're after. I tested it in devtools and works perfectly

Comment: that is working on chrome dev tool. Thanks, anyway i noticed that theme did not even declared .em-main and i was applying css on '.container_24 em-main'